# text processing rows to columns for a block of lines Awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, text-formatting

i have input file like below .i need to reformat the text as o/p  mentioned.
I using the awk got from this forum but it is displayed based on the List A columns count.
Please help

```
awk 'BEGIN{ max=0 }
 /^List/{ if(k && k>max) { max=k; idx=c } ++c; k=0 }
 NF{ a[c][++k]=$0 }
 END{ 
     for(i=1;i<=max;i++) 
         for(j=1;j<=c;j++) printf "%s%s",a[j][i],(j==c)?ORS:"\t" 
 }' filename | column -ts$'\t'
```

Input:-

```
List A
Hello
how are you
fine

List B
good: Fine_health
hello: world_free
some: unkon_text
some: unkon_text1
some: unkon_text2
```

expected output

```
List A       List B
Hello        good: Fine_health
how are you  hello: world_free
fine         some: unkon_text
             some: unkon_text1
             some: unkon_text2
```

Comment: I get the good output with GNU awk

Comment: you mean gawk working fine?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: You set `idx=c` in your code but never use `idx`, maybe there's some missing use of it? In general, use more meaningful variable names and that'll help you figure out what's wrong with your code if it's not doing what you want.

Comment: Does not work for me. It only outputs the first 4 lines -- the last two in List B are omitted.

Answer (score 1):

The script as posted does *not* work. It only outputs the first 4 lines -- the last two in List B are omitted.

The issue is that the value of `k` counts the lines in each list. But it is only stored into `max` at the *start* of each list, so the length of the second list is not taken into account.

The fix is to repeat the `if(k && k>max) { max=k; }` as the first line in the END block, when the last List had been read.

That reveals another bug. Those last two lines are not columnised -- they appear in column 1. The issue there appears to be that `column` does not recognise a zero-length first column: if I force a `.` at the start of each value, it columnises List B correctly.

Personally, I would columnise in awk -- save the max length of any entry in each column, and space them out with a `%-*s` width specifier. That might be what the unused variable `idx` was meant to be for.

EDIT: Yes, definitely a bug in column. The tab is actioned for `Four`, but ignored for `Three`.

There is a `-n` option which honours leading and repeated separators, but is documented as a Debian extension (and also works in my Mint (Ubuntu) distribution). Without `-n`, empty values are discarded (i.e. delimiters at the start and end of a line are ignored), and multiple adjacent delimiters are merged.

```
$ cat -vet foo
One$
 Two$
^IThree$
q^IFour$
$ column -t -s $'\t' foo | cat -vet
One$
 Two$
Three$
q      Four$
```

EDIT Two: This version has more functionality.

(a) Avoids the bug in the `column` command, by doing the tabulation internally (also avoiding the extra process, and the memory overhead of having both awk and column store the whole data set in memory).

(b) Accepts multiple file args (or stdin by default, so it works in a pipeline).

(c) Works for an arbitrary number of output columns, not just two.

(d) Fixes the originally posted bug (where the length of the rightmost column was ignored).

```
#! /bin/bash

Awk='
BEGIN { Gap = 2; }
/^List/ { ++col; row=0; }
NF { X[++row, col] = $0;
    if (mxrow < row) mxrow = row;
    if (len[col] < length($0)) len[col] = length($0);
}
function Column (Local, r, c) {
    for (r = 1; r <= mxrow; ++r) {
        for (c = 1; c < col; ++c) 
            printf ("%-*s", Gap + len[c], X[r,c]);
        printf ("%-s\n", X[r,c]);
    }
}
END { Column( ); }
'
    awk "${Awk}" "${@:-}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @a = slurp.split("\n\n"); @a.=map(*.split("\n", :skip-empty));  \
            my $length = @a>>.elems.max;  for ^$length -> $i {  \
               print ($_[$i] // q[ ]) ~ q[|] for @a; "".say;    \
               };'  filename.txt  |  column -ts'|'
```

Above an answer is coded in Raku. Lines are `slurp`ed in (read all at once) and `split` on paragraphs (`\n\n`). Paragraphs are assigned to the `@a` array. In the next statement each paragraph element is split on `\n` into lines. A `max` length of `elems` elements is computed for the `@a` array.

Each position (read: paragraph) of the `@a` array is then `print`ed out to the full max `$length`, and where a sub-element (read: line) of each position is undefined (using the `//` "defined-or" operator), a `q[ ]` blank-space is inserted (column 'placeholder'). Columns are `~` concatenated with a trailing `|` bar, and each row is then terminated with a newline (using `"".say;`).

To give the output desired by the OP, the unix utility `column` is used to split columns on the inserted `|` bar separator. For a Raku-only solution, replacing `~ q[|]` with `~ qb[\t]` returns tab-separated output.

Sample Input:

```
List A
Hello
how are you
fine

List B
good: Fine_health
hello: world_free
some: unkon_text
some: unkon_text1
some: unkon_text2
```

Sample Output:

```
List A        List B
Hello         good: Fine_health
how are you   hello: world_free
fine          some: unkon_text
              some: unkon_text1
              some: unkon_text2
```

https://raku.org
https://rakudo.org

Answer (score 1):

Your input and output samples imply that you simply want to join up the two lists. You don't need awk for this task.
Break up your input file into two: lista and listb and then join them up with paste command:

```
paste lista listb
```

You can automate the break up of your input file into two files (assuming that each section is separated by one or two blank lines) then use awk with RS option as blank:

```
awk -v RS= '{print > ("list" NR ".txt")}' listall
```

This generates files list1.txt and list2.txt

then:

```
paste list1.txt list2.txt
```

Comment: The `paste` works fine (provided you separate the two List sections manually first). But the tabulation still fails, because of the bug in `column` which I noted in my reply.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant  If I set `column` to find a space or `|` pipe in the first column, it works. That means using `awk` or `raku` to output a space or `|` pipe as needed for blank lines.

Comment: @jubilatious1  I noted "if I force a `.` at the start of each value ...", but I don't like adding chars to user inputs to fix bugs in standard commands, especially where you cannot `tr` them out, because the real data might contain a space or pipe in places.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant agreed. This is where I'd rather provide an all-in-one solution using `sprintf` or similar (in Raku). However, it has been edifying to learn more about `column`. It seems if you hand a line to `column` and there's no first column 'placeholder' and/or 'separator', then `column` will think you mean that the first real characters in that line ("List B") belong in the first column.  I'm not sure `column` has any way to determine otherwise?  Cheers.

Comment: @jubilatious1  The `column -n` option honours leading and repeated separators, but is documented as a Debian extension.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant the `column -n` option is not available for my MacOS (BSD) version.

Comment: @jubilatious1  My posted solution works in GNU/awk, awk --traditional, mawk and nawk. awk can be cumbersome, but with 50 years on client sites I value portability above all.