# Something like `paste` but with a vertical alignment after a delimiter?

Tags: text-processing

I want to paste two files together, but with vertical alignment after a section delimiter line `::`. Here’s what I mean.

Contents of `file1`:

```
Apple
Banana
Carrot
::
Durian
```

Contents of `file2`:

```
Energy
Flight
::
Gravity
Heartbreak
```

Desired output:

```
Apple Energy
Banana Flight
Carrot 
::
Durian Gravity
 Heartbreak
```

So far I know `paste` will *almost* do what I want (without the nice vertical alignment); another option is to split `file1` and `file2` into multiple files, then concatenate the results together, but I want to avoid that if I can. How can I do this?

I don’t strictly need a solution that uses `paste`. Anything that works works!

Comment: See `man column` for something that provides this feature. I'm not clear how `paste` can deal with re-alignment after the `::` group separator lines -- we might be into `awk` territory here.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant `column` can't insert blank fields to adjust alignment vertically.

Comment: @Kusalananda  Quite so: the vertical alignment needs to be padded to match up the `::` parts *before* the paste. Also, I recently had a battle with `column` because it treats multiple separators as one, so fails to columnise empty fields. You need a placeholder for empty fields. Hence `awk` may be the easiest solution.

Comment: @Kusalananda  Here we are: the `column` problem described, and my solution in awk for a similar problem. `https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/724928/text-processing-rows-to-columns-for-a-block-of-lines-awk/725043#725043`

Comment: Okay, it sounds like I should be on the lookout for an `awk` solution. Should I edit this question to clarify that I’m not strictly asking for a `paste` solution, or is that clear already?

Comment: @SophieWeigle I changed the tagging a bit to make it more generic. If you want to clarify the question further, then go ahead and edit it.

Comment: @SophieWeigle - just curious, have these files always the same number of sections?

Comment: @don_crissti In this case yes!

Assuming they don’t, let’s say the desired output is that after the shorter file ends, the sections of the output are identical to the sections of the longer file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    blockSep = "::"
}
FNR == 1 {
    numBlocks[++fileNr] = 0
}
(FNR == 1) || ($0 == blockSep) {
    numLines[fileNr,++numBlocks[fileNr]] = 0
}
$0 != blockSep {
    vals[fileNr,numBlocks[fileNr],++numLines[fileNr,numBlocks[fileNr]]] = $0
}
END {
    maxBlocks = ( numBlocks[1] > numBlocks[2] ? numBlocks[1] : numBlocks[2] )
    for ( blockNr=1; blockNr<=maxBlocks; blockNr++ ) {
        maxLines = ( numLines[1,blockNr] > numLines[2,blockNr] ? numLines[1,blockNr] : numLines[2,blockNr] )
        for ( lineNr=1; lineNr<=maxLines; lineNr++ ) {
            print vals[1,blockNr,lineNr], vals[2,blockNr,lineNr]
        }
        if ( blockNr < maxBlocks ) {
            print blockSep
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
Apple Energy
Banana Flight
Carrot
::
Durian Gravity
 Heartbreak
```

Comment: Thank you, works great!! Could you add what assumptions this makes about the file contents? (For example: whether the string “::” appears anywhere else besides the delimiter lines, whether spaces appear in each line, and whether the two files have the same number of sections.)

Comment: No assumptions that spring to mind, I expect it'll work for any input files of any number of blocks (sections) per file or any numbers of lines per block with any spaces anywhere and `::`s appearing anywhere else. Oh, one assumption I suppose is that you want to get all the output for both input files, not truncate either of them if one is smaller than the other in any way. If that's wrong in some way just change the `>` to `<` in the `maxBlocks` and/or `maxLines` calculations ternary expressions as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This is an *extremely* hackish solution that works with your example data because the two files have only the `::` line in common and because the files only contain single words (no spaces).  I would therefore consider it extremely fragile and not at all generic.

It parses the side-by-side `diff` output, so it is `diff` that does the vertical alignment.

```bash
$ diff -y file1 file2 | awk -v OFS='\t' 'NF == 3 { print $1, $3; next } $2 == "<" { print $1; next } $1 == ">" { print "", $2; next } { print $1 }'
Apple   Energy
Banana  Flight
Carrot
::
Durian  Gravity
        Heartbreak
```

The `awk` code that parses the `diff -y` output outputs selected parts of each line depending on the number of fields and the contents of certain parts of the data.